# Is there a way to change the current directory by an TextIOWrapper/Text from a file?

Tags: python

So I am programming an operating system that is like an ms-dos os. Is there a way to change the directory using info from a file? in the file called 'Threadeddir.txt' I have put a file path to my directory that I want to change to is there a way to do this? Code and Error linked below:
Code:

```
if istdirempty:
    bootingdir = open("Threadeddir.txt", "r")
    bootdir = bootingdir.read()
    os.chdir(bootdir)
    bootingdir.close()
    Logging()
```

As for the error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ''
```

Is there a way to fix this? I have tried alot of things and nothing worked.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _change the directory_ ?

Comment: By changing the directory i mean the directory that the os module is using.

Comment: I'm still confused, sorry.

Comment: By doing 'import os' you get access to file changing commands but any files you edit should be in your directory you can change your directory by doing 'os.chdir(directory filepath)'

Comment: Alright, that part I understand.

Comment: It appears from the error message that `bootdir` is empty. The error might come from the content of `Threadeddir.txt`. Please provide additional information like the current working dir and the content of the above file.